# Testing value from a list, replacing from another in Python

Tags: python, list

Please, what would be "the ultimate Python" way to test whether some simple variable X is in a list (or a tuple) and if True then to return value from another list (or a tuple) at the same position? Would dictionary serve better?

Answer (score 4):

The `list.index()` or `tuple.index()` method returns the first index of a matching value:

```
def mapped_value(somelist, someotherlist, value):
    try:
        index = somelist.index(value)
    except ValueError:
        return None
    return someotherlist[index]
```

A `ValueError` is raised if the `value` is not present, at which point `None` is returned instead.

This could be made a little more compact and guard against a shorter `someotherlist` too by catching `IndexError`:

```
def mapped_value(somelist, someotherlist, value):
    try:
        return someotherlist[somelist.index(value)]
    except (ValueError, IndexError):
        return None
```

However, a dictionary mapping values to other values would be much more convenient, yes. You can convert your two lists to a dictionary with:

```
mapping = dict(zip(somelist, someotherlist))
return mapping.get(value)
```

where it is assumed that the items in `somelist` are both unique and hashable.

Demo:

```
>>> somelist = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
>>> someotherlist = ['spam', 'ham', 'eggs']
>>> mapped_value(somelist, someotherlist, 'bar')
'ham'
>>> mapping = dict(zip(somelist, someotherlist))
>>> mapping.get('bar')
'ham'
```

Comment: `try: return someotherlist[somelist.index(value)]` `except (ValueError,IndexError): return None` would be more similar to the `dict` example...

Comment: @JonClements: Because `someotherlist` could be shorter, you mean? I've made the assumption both lists are the same length, yes.